# Picture doesn't show on iPhone when running app

Tags: ios

I have set the backgroundColor to a picture which is located in the project folder. When I run the app in the simulator the pic is shown. But when running on my real iPhone it's just white. What can be causing this? Could it be because I have <0.5gb free on both the computer and iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

That should be plenty of free memory. When adding the file to your project, and make sure you choose the options for the image to be copied into the project and to be part of the target.

EDIT: my above suggestion is only useful if the UIImageView you are trying to load points to a picture, and I guess in this case you are just using a blank UIImageView and setting background color.

Also, you might want to look at the arrangement (ie. send to back, send to front, etc. Try sending to front in case there was something in front of it blocking the view) I think these options are in the menu bar under Design --> Arrangement

Comment: I'm adding the picture as backgroundColor to an UIView

Answer (score 0):

First try to `Uninstall` the app  `Clean` the project then `Install` and then check if not then.

Second there may some issue with picture spelling `Case senstive` or `Not` As The `iPhone` is case sensitive, but the `simulator` is not because `iPhone` file system is case sensitive and `Mac OS` is not

Third 
Add a `break point` where you add `UIImage`

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a_image.png"];
```

Then on the console `"po [imgView image]`"

If it is nil then either the resource is not getting copied correctly into the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation.
It seems the simulator - Xcode is cacheing the image somewhere, but at build time is loosing.

Try: uninstall the app from simulator, device.
Clean the project.
Force close XCode, not just the project, close it.
Open, clean project, build
At this step should match the device and simulator behaviour, hopefully it is there the desired image.

Answer (score 0):

Please check spelling of the image name you used. In actual devices it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post some code?

You'll want to add the image not as a `backgroundColor`, but as a `UIImageView` subview.

```
// load the image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

// create the image view using the image
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

// add the image view as a subview
[yourview addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: I added an imageview on the view instead as you showed. It's strange, because the image show on the simulator as before but it doesn't on my iphone as before. But on another subview on the first view a have an imageview, and that's image does show up on both simulator and my device??

Comment: As @bunty-madan said above "there may some issue with picture spelling Case senstive or Not As The iPhone is case sensitive, but the simulator is not because iPhone file system is case sensitive and Mac OS is not". Make sure you are correctly capitalizing your image filename. This is most likely the simulator versus device issue.

Comment: I've checked it but it doesn't work. But the picture in the other subview does show up where it should, and if I add that same picture to the first view (which i had problem with)it DOES show up

Comment: It looks like you've already done the test of deleting the app from your phone and the simulator. And you've been able to use another image successfully. You've checked that the CASE of the filename is EXACTLY the same as the actual file. The only other thing I can think of is to delete your project files in the DerivedData directory and build and test again. To do that, go to File/Project Settings and go to the directory shown. Close Xcode and then delete your project's directory. This will cause everything in your project to be built from scratch with no other files left hanging around.